# elastic beanstalk environment does not appear in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am struggling with an AWS problem. I login to the AWS web console with master creds. I create a user with admin role (arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess)  using IAM, and from that user I get access_id and access_key.

I run `eb init` using the CLI, and put in the access_id/access_key. I then try to run `eb deploy` to the one existing environment and it says the environment doesn't exist:

> ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - No Environment found for
>   EnvironmentName = 'xxx'.

So I create a new environment with `eb create` and then I run `eb deploy` and it works. But the new env does not show up in the console!...and I get a 502 Gateway error when I use `eb open`.

My only hypothesis is that somehow I am logged in with the wrong creds? If I open ~/.aws/config it shows the expected access_id and access_key and no other relevant env vars should be overriding that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok so yeah the reason why the environment I created at the command line wasn't appearing the console is because I was in the wrong region in the web console:

[image]

in the top right corner of the console, there is region dropdown. Search the relevant regions - your environments are only visible in the right region apparently. (I wish there was a number next to the region in the dropdown - the number of envs in that region).

I assume that the error at the command line - ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - No Environment found for EnvironmentName = 'xxx', occurred because the wrong region was assumed? That seems weird, but it's my best guess.